# How to delete unshelved branch in git-p4

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

I don't know how to delete the branch created using `git p4 unshelve`

When I type: `git branch --all` I see all branches including "**remotes**" and "**unshelved**"

```
C:\gitWorkspace\myWorkspace>git branch --all
  feature_2
* feature_1
  master
  remotes/p4-unshelved/161257
  remotes/p4-unshelved/161257.0
  remotes/p4-unshelved/161924
  remotes/p4/HEAD -> p4/master
  remotes/p4/master
```

Then I try to delete using this: `git branch -d remotes/p4-unshelved/161257.0`

But I get an error: `error: branch 'remotes/p4-unshelved/161257.0' not found.`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
git update-ref -d refs/remotes/p4-unshelved/161257
```

Don't forget to prefix the "remote branch" name with "**refs/**"